# iText Reporting on a continuous paper in dot matrix printer

Tags: java, printing, itext

Please Check the attached Sample Image -

[image]

I want to print my report in a continuous paper on a dot matrix printer. There can have N number of customer in the report. And for each customer there will be two copy of the report. Customer copy and Bank Copy. In the continuous paper between both the copy there will be perforation. Each copy (Customer Copy or Bank Copy) size is almost a4. But in the pre printed page both the copy are side by side. How can I create such a PDF in iText ?

Comment: That is more depending on the software used to print the PDF and the printer driver.

Comment: I think iText NUPTOOL can help in this context. Am I right ? http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=115

Comment: Seems that you want to 2-up two A4 pages so that they can be printed on an A3 page. The example you refer to should work to create such a PDF (some minor changes may be necessary). Whether or not that PDF will print correctly on a dot matrix printer will depend on what @mkl mentions.

Comment: Thanks Bruno and mkl for your valuable comments.